# Running tomcat app as low privilege user?

Tags: tomcat, drools, tomcat8, kie

I'm totally new to tomcat so I might be missing something stupidly simple.
I'm trying to run drools' kie-workbench 7.5 in tomcat 8. I configured tomcat and the app to work with `root` but it doesn't work with user `tomcat` that I gave ownership and 777 privileges to the whole TOMCAT_HOME directory.
I used this [ansible recipe](https://github.com/ChristopherDavenport/ansible-role-universal-tomcat) to install tomcat after I tried manually with no luck with both.
`192.168.50.8:8080` loads tomcat but when I try to access `192.168.50.8:8080/kie-drools-wb-7.5.0.Final-tomcat8` which is the address of the app I get this [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1mk8.jpg).
I tried to run tomcat with this command: `sudo -u tomcat TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh`
I also tried running it with `jsvc` with [these instructions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html)
And running it as a service doesn't work from my manual installation or the Ansible recipe.

**Edit:**
logs after launching tomcat with [jsvc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html):
[catalina.err](https://pastebin.com/Z2bSs4yx), [catalina.2018-02-11.log](https://pastebin.com/9pfvxcCz), [localhost_access_log..2018-02-11.txt](https://pastebin.com/nnakJCvy), [localhost.2018-02-11.log](https://pastebin.com/yZxjFz7Y)

Comment: What's the error when it fails?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EstebanAliverti. It just shows that error page I linked. or should I include some logs?

Comment: But what about tomcat's logs?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti added the logs after launching tomcat and accessing 192.168.50.8:8080. can't add more links because don't have enough reputation. if this is no good I will add logs of connecting to the app.

Answer (score 0):

The logs are showing the following error:

`Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /.index/datasources/write.lock`

Check that you have the correct permissions over that directory.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Now it shows `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied` after I gave privileges to the whole _.index_ directory.

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace?

Comment: It is apparently failing when creating the internal git repository the workbench uses to store all the assets. When manually running tomcat, this repository is usually located under tomcat's bin directory.
According to the documentation, you can use a system variable to specify the location of the repository: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.workbenchdata

Comment: So I should set `$WORKING_DIRECTORY` variable? What directory should I set it to?

Comment: This is the log after I created `WORKING_DIRECTORY=TOMCAT_HOME/bin`  https://pastebin.com/836mkAbm

Comment: No, you should set the value of `org.uberfire.nio.git.dir` to a directory where `tomcat` user can write to.

Comment: Some pages suggest to add in standalone.xml but I don't have one.

Comment: check on how to set JAVA_OPT when starting tomcat. I can't do anything else for you. This is getting out of topic.